# Framework for cross-platform development

Tags: android, ios, c++, c#, qt

I want to start focusing myself on mobile development, and based on a google research I've come to the conclusion that leaves me with only two options, since I would like to target multiple devices/OS. Based on experience which framework provides a better development experience.

I would like to give a list of some of the things I am looking for:

- I favor C++ over .Net, but have more experience with the latter. (I am comfortable with either)
- Performance is a big thing for me. (even if it's for something small).
- Qt Mobile's license fees are scary. (I look to eventually make my app commercial and/or sell apps to others).
- I don't know which one has more time around. (Community size).
- I don't know which paradigms or patterns one favors over the other.
- Code maintainability is just as important as performance.
- I know very little of either framework internally.
- Deployment complexity (which one makes this easier?).

Based on each point which one would win? Or is there another candidate fitting even better?

Comment: I guess you can call it a comparison, but the purpose is to know based on some traits, which one I should start learning. My knowledge of both frameworks is very shallow so I decided to try to make it somewhat more educational by adding the list.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note that this site doesn't feature requests for product comparisions: SR is about suggesting specific software for specific needs you define. For details, see: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/69/185) I rephrased your question a little to make it fit here – and hope that meets your intention (otherwise we've got to close it).